# How to set read replica for MySQL RDS instance without few tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

How to set read replica for AWS RDS without data from few tables? I would like to exclude a set of tables (say tableA, tableB) while replicating from databaseA to databaseB.

How should I set it for a production AWS RDS instance?
Post replication, I will be making changes only to tableA, tableB and not other tables which are being replicated from databaseA

Comment: I am not sure there is a feature as such. Could not see it in the documentation and found this in the forums https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=533462